# I want to show two view as connected like in treeview

Tags: android, canvas, tree, treeview

[image]

As you you can see the image,

I have divided the layout into three parts of the screen and showing three level tree on the activity page.

the top node  will always be single below nodes can be more than one so I just need an idea that how can I connect one view with another in the centre using canvas drawing

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
            Path path = new Path();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            c.drawPaint(paint);

            path.moveTo(startX, startY);
            path.lineTo(startX, 1000);

            path.close();
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setPathEffect(null);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            c.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: How did you setup 3 layout in same screen? Use fragment or something?

Comment: Did you use Static layout in xml?

Comment: @AshokkumarAdichill i am using static layout. because i want to show only three level on screen

Comment: @nhoxbypass no dear not  using fragment it is single activity in which root is constraintlayout in it i have three relative layout which i want to join by using lines

Answer (score 1):

[Find the file here..](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oN8V5j9Q3x9o7GToG-VHHxqFt67AXBx2/view?usp=sharing)

The file using many view for arrange them like hierarchy.

Comment: thanks ashokkumar but i cant mark it as an answer since it is static implementation. no of nodes may change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library [TreeView](https://github.com/Team-Blox/TreeView) instead of doing it yourself. With the library you can represent all kinds of directed rooted trees.

The tree above you could represent as follows:

```
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode("root");
rootNode.addChild(new TreeNode(child1));
rootNode.addChild(new TreeNode(child2));
```

Then define the lib in xml like any other view as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <de.blox.treeview.TreeView
           android:id="@+id/treeview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:lineColor="@android:color/red">
      </de.blox.treeview.TreeView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To use the custom attributes (for example, to represent the edges in red like you did) you have to add the namespace first:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

You can make the node Layout how you like. Just define a layout file and use it with the adapter.

**Edit:**
The library is in an early stage of development and in the meantime the api has changed! Since I can't customize the post every time, just follow the steps in the description.